# FacetGrid plot with aggregate in Seaborn/other library

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby, seaborn, facet-grid

I've toy-dataframe like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({'cat': ['a', 'a', 'a', 'b', 'b', 'b'], 'n1': [1,1,1,4,5,6], 'n2': [6,5,2,2,2,1]})
```

I want to groupby by `cat` and plot histograms for `n1` and `n2`, additionally I want to plot those histograms without grouping, so first, transform data to seaborn format:

```
df2 = pd.melt(df, id_vars='cat', value_vars=['n1', 'n2'], value_name='value')
```

second add "all":

```
df_all = df2.copy()
df_all['cat'] = 'all'
df3 = pd.concat([df2, df_all])
```

Finally plot:

```
g = sns.FacetGrid(df2, col="variable", row="cat")
g.map(plt.hist, 'value', ec="k")
```

[image]

I wonder, if it could be done in more elegant, concise way, without creating `df3` or `df2`. Different library could be used.

Comment: That seems pretty clean to me. If you have to do this a lot, build a function that takes df as input, performs the melt and outputs either the final df3 or directly the plot.

Answer (score 1):

As I mentioned in my comment, I think what you do is perfectly fine. Craft a function if needed to perform often. Nevertheless, you might be interested in [pandas_profiling](https://pandas-profiling.github.io/pandas-profiling/docs/master/index.html). This describes in detail the profile of your data, and in an interactive way. In my opinion, this is probably overkill for what you want to do, but I'll let you be the judge of that ;)

```
import pandas_profiling
df.profile_report()
```

Extract of the interactive output:
[image: pandas profiling]

Comment: Thanks, I was thinking that seaborn provides parameter like "include_aggregate=True", that I'm not aware. In such way solution will be more declarative.